# compile opencv fails on libpng/png.h on gentoo

Tags: opencv, libpng, gentoo

When compiling opencv on gentoo on arm64 I get:

```
' fatal error: libpng/png.h: No such file or directory '
```

it seems I need to

```
cd /usr/include;ln -s libpng16 libpng
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Come on - try a bit harder. How do you think anyone will be able to help you? You don't say what command you used that caused the error, nor what packages you have installed in support, nor what version of OpenCV you are trying to build, nor why you think you need to make a symlink....

Comment: command used --> `emerge opencv`, which is bog standard gentoo installation of any software.  The version, and dependencies are listed and installed by the ebuild: https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/media-libs/opencv/opencv-3.4.1-r2.ebuild and I have also tried downgrading to 3.3.0-r5 as well.  I think I need a symlink as the error is quite succinct about not finding png.h in the libpng directory, which is not there in /usr/include, but there is a libpng16 right next to it, and the error goes away if I make said symlink.

Comment: My question is this the fault of gentoo for not symlinking that directory, or libpng for moving that directory to libpng16 or opencv for looking for it in the wrong place?

Comment: it seems libv4l has similar issues, perhaps this belongs on the gentoo forums --> https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8252146.html#8252146